# Git Pull from a Forked Repository

Tags: git, github

I recently forked a repository.  The repository has been updated and I would like to have the updated version. When I git pull, does it pull from my repository on github? Or will it pull from the forked repository?

From my understand when I fork I have access to 3 versions of the repository.

1. On my local machine.
2. My forked version on my personal github repository
3. The repository that I forked from.

So if I git pull from my local machine, will that pull from my personal repository where the project is forked, or will it pull from the project repository where everyone is working from?

**I cloned the repository to my local machine by git clone [https link] (my own forked version).
**I'm in the process of trying to find the rest of the information Wooble requested, thanks for the suggestions! I will try to get that information asap.

Thanks!

Comment: It will pull by default from whatever remote is set as the default for pulls. You don't tell us how you cloned the repo to your local machine, or what other remotes you may have set up. If you cloned your own fork and never did anything else to your remotes setup, presumably the default is to pull from your fork.

Comment: Sorry Wooble, I'll provide that information in a moment, I'm a bit new to pulling from forks and didn't realize that was essential information.

Comment: `git remote -v` will tell you pretty much everything you need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have remotes to both your forked repository and the original repository you forked from. Run `git remote -v` to see a list of remotes available.

You can choose to pull from the listed remotes:

```
git pull <remote_name> <branch_name>
```

Doing a `git pull` will pull from your default remote, which in your case is your repository not the original one.